# Django update all fields implicitly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When using django rest framework, I have a method to update a model based on inputted form data.

SpellSerializer.py:

```
from rest_framework import views, serializers, status
from .models import Spell

class SpellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Spell
        # fields = ('id', 'owner', 'Name', 'School', 'Subschool')
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):    
        user = None
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
            user = request.user

        validated_data['owner'] = user.id
        return Spell.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.Name = validated_data.get('Name', instance.Name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Is there a way that I can have all the fields on the model update with the validated_data if the names of the fields all line up?  (Aka `validated_data.Name` matches `instance.Name`, `validated_data.Otherfield` is the same as `instance.Otherfield`, instead of having to explicity list all the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use serializer's [`partial=True`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates) argument. In your view:

```
serializer = CommentSerializer(instance, data={'name': 'foo bar'}, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

This is not raise error if other fields is not provided.

**UPD**

If you mean you don't want to specify `instance.somefield = validated_data['somefield']` you can use following syntax in serializer:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.Name = validated_data.get('Name', instance.Name)
    [setattr(instance, k, v) for k, v in validated_data.items()]
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: It actually is in the serializer class.  I updated my original post with the full class (at least the relevant parts).  Where would I put that, and do I still have to list out all the fields?

Comment: @cclloyd so you cannot change view and want to make it on serializer level?  Is it correct? Not sure but afraid it not possible.

Comment: I wasn't using any views, just whatever views are generated by DRF.  It said to provide methods (create, update, etc) for each method I want to manipulate data.  It also had a create method that worked without listing all the views (provided above)

Comment: @cclloyd I guess I understand what do you mean. Check updated answer.